# Excel formula - if text return text or if number perform calculation or if error show as blank

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a survey question whose answers may be either a number or a text string:

- **Survey Question:**  "% using each product"
- **Possible Answers:**

  1. # (a number)
  2. "Not used"
  3. "Not applicable"
  4. "Used - but unsure of %"

To do this, I need the formula to vary depending on whether the cell contains text or numbers.

How do I adapt the formula `=IFERROR(B2*E2, " ")` so that column F shows the calculation when there is a number in column B  (ie what I have in the formula so far) but if the cell contains text, that text is returned instead. So F6 would be "not applicable" whilst F7 would be "not used" etc. Hope the screenshot below makes my problem easier to understand.

**Screenshot of Data**
[image: screenshot of data]

- column B contains the answers to the survey question;
- column E contains a number or a text string;
- column F contains one of:

  1. the product of column B and column E, or
  2. the value of column B if it is a text string, or
  3. nothing (blank) if column B is not a text string, and the product of B and E would result in an error

Comment: Thank you - I've added the screenshot - hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is close.  If `E2` is always a number whenever `B2` is also a number, then simply replacing the space `" "` you were returning (a blank is `""`) with `B2` would give you what you want:

```
=IFERROR(B2*E2,B2)
```

If it is possible that `B2` could be a number, while at the same time `E2` was not, then the formula would need to be modified to address that.

For example:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),
    IFERROR(B2*E2,""),
    B2)
```

The IF Function tests for the condition where `B2` is a number:

1. IF condition **TRUE,**
   then return the product of `B2` and `E2`, or return BLANK if that product would result in an error
2. IF Condition **FALSE,**
   then return `B2`

There are other variations that would achieve the same GOAL.

For example:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),
    IF(ISNUMBER(E2),
       B2*E2,""), 
    B2)
```

- `Is B2 a number?`

  - **TRUE:**   `Is E2 a number?`

    - **TRUE:**   `=B2*E2`
    - **FALSE**   `=""`
  - **FALSE:**   `=B2`

Comment: This is amazing - thank you!

Comment: My pleasure.  FYI, I suggested an edit to your question to make it more clear to others.  Keep contributing!